# Replace or remove mutliple lines of text in oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Could any one help me to repalce or remove set of lines using a replace or regex replace function,and what would be the string pattern to find and replace

lines to be replaced from below text

```
</properties>

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<properties>
```

Text

```
<COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>global.grxml</COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>

  <COLLECT_INPUTMODES>voice dtmf</COLLECT_INPUTMODES>

  <CONF_INPUTMODES>dtmf</CONF_INPUTMODES>

</ROW>

</properties>

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<properties>

<ROW>

  <MODULE_NAME>main_menu_phone</MODULE_NAME>

  <MODULE_DESCRIPTION>Main Menu for Customers with silver membership</MODULE_DESCRIPTION>

  <MODULE_TYPE>phone</MODULE_TYPE>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is plain **text** and not **XML**, then you could simply use **REPLACE**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT '
  3  <COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>global.grxml</COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>
  4  <COLLECT_INPUTMODES>voice dtmf</COLLECT_INPUTMODES>
  5  <CONF_INPUTMODES>dtmf</CONF_INPUTMODES>
  6  </ROW>
  7  </properties>
  8  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  9  <properties>
 10  <ROW>
 11  <MODULE_NAME>main_menu_phone</MODULE_NAME>
 12  <MODULE_DESCRIPTION>Main Menu for Customers with silver membership</MODULE_DESCRIPTION>
 13  <MODULE_TYPE>phone</MODULE_TYPE>' str
 14    FROM dual
 15    )
 16  SELECT REPLACE(str, '</properties>
 17  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 18  <properties>', '') new_str
 19  FROM data;

NEW_STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>global.grxml</COLLECT_PARALLELGRAMMAR1>
<COLLECT_INPUTMODES>voice dtmf</COLLECT_INPUTMODES>
<CONF_INPUTMODES>dtmf</CONF_INPUTMODES>
</ROW>

<ROW>
<MODULE_NAME>main_menu_phone</MODULE_NAME>
<MODULE_DESCRIPTION>Main Menu for Customers with silver membership</MODULE_DESCRIPTION>
<MODULE_TYPE>phone</MODULE_TYPE>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion..but this is not a plain text..it a xml file getting stored in clob type

Comment: @Anirudh But you have mentioned "*lines of text*" in your question and topic title. You have no where mentioned it is **XML**.

Comment: sorry.initially i was trying with XML as a text.But it is getting stored in clob and i need to replace the pattern of string which i mentioned above then put clob content to a file